# jQuery scrollTo.js keyboard control misbehaving

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollto

**Here's a live version of the page in question: http://agoodman.com.au/index1.html**

I'm using Bootstrap to build a one-pager website, and scrollTo is being used to scroll up/down the different sections. There is a top navbar, with the code:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#intro" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#intro', 600 );">Top</a></li>
  <li><a href="#service" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#service', 600 );">What we do</a></li>
  <li><a href="#howitworks" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#howitworks', 600 );">How it works</a></li>
  <li><a href="#fees" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#fees', 600 );">Our fees</a></li>
  <li><a href="#why" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#why', 600 );">Why do it?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#map" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#map', 600 );">Map</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#contact', 600 );">Contact</a></li>
</ul>​
```

The scrolling works fine when you click on the navbar with the mouse, no weird behaviour at all. I'm then using this jquery code to control the navbar with the up/down arrows of the keyboard:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
          var p = $("li.active");
          if (e.keyCode === 38) {
          p.prev().find("a").click();
          } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
          p.next().find('a').click();
          }
        });
```

This works, for the most part. However, there are two problems that I'd like to solve:

**1.** When pressing up/down, the page moves up/down one small jump (as if pressing an arrow key on any website does) and *then* scrolls to the next div. I tried putting event.preventDefualt(); in the jquery if/else statement but it didn't do anything. Any ideas on how to prevent the default up/down action here?

**2.** Pressing the "up" key causes the page to scroll up *two* sections rather than one. For instance, go to the "#why" section, then press up. It scrolls to "#fees" then scrolls again to "#howitworks". Perhaps scrollspy.js is conflicting here?

Would appreciate being pointed in the right direction in this one.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keydown`. Then either `return true` and `e.preventDefault()` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why the page would skip, could be because of the find and the position of where you are in your hash list. I wrote a small snippet for code organization so its easier to debug where you are.

**EDIT:** Okay, I finally revised the code to make it work properly. Earlier, I kind of figured it wouldn't work, but I wanted to give you a skeleton of how to handle the scrolls.

Note:

1. $("a") fetches a list of all anchors
2. window.location.hash.slice(1) gets the current hash that you are on, in case you clicked on a link
3. anchors.index is the index of the anchor you are on (gathered from step 1)
4. anchors.get simply fetches the next position
5. currentHash.hash is the hash of the next address you are fetching from

   ```
   var anchors = $("a.links");
   var currentPos = 0;
   var nextPos = 0;
   var current = window.location.hash.slice(1); //get current hash;

   $('#navbar').scrollspy();

   $(document).ready(function(){       
       $(document).keyup(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
           currentPos = anchors.index($('a[href$="' + $('input[name="hash"]').val() + '"]'));
           //currentPos = anchors.index($('a[href$="' + current + '"]'));
            if(e.keyCode === 38){
               scrollUp(currentPos);
            } else if (e.keyCode === 40){
               scrollDown(currentPos);
            }

       });

       function scrollUp(pos){
           currentHash = anchors.get(pos-1);
           if(!(currentHash===undefined) && (pos-1) >= 0){
               current = currentHash.hash;
           }
            $(document).scrollTo(current,600);

       }

       function scrollDown(pos){
           currentHash = anchors.get(pos+1);
           if(!(currentHash===undefined)){
               current = currentHash.hash;
           }
            $(document).scrollTo(current,600);
       }
   });
   ```

Tip:

I'd associate a class to your links like:

```
 <a class="links" href="#service" ....>
```

then in step 1 of the notes you could do a selector:

```
 $(a) will then be $(a.links)
```

**EDIT2** : I edited the above javascript to make use of the changes below:

I found an unfortunate way to use scrollspy. Apparently, they use prototypes to wrap up their functions, and you really can't call those methods directly. So the workaround is this:

place this html code into your webpage:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="" />
```

Then open up scrollspy, go down to the prototyping where it gives you "activates" and enter in this code:

```
$('input[name="hash"]').val(this.activeTarget);
```

above the line:

```
active.trigger('activate')
```

Comment: Hah. You're right about my spelling. However, your code didn't work in chrome, and in fact disabled the keyboard controls completely. Setting  var current = window.location.hash.splice(1) - I'm unfamiliar with what this does, but I assume it gets the current window location - seems less efficient than the current setup. I'm using ScrollSpy which sets the navbar's current location to li.active, so I'm using that to control the page.

Comment: please look at my new edit, I had to fetch the plugin that you used and spent about 20 mins revising it :)

Comment: This fixes the double-scrolling problem, but unfortunately adds more problems. Say you're looking at the "how it works section", then you scroll down to the bottom of the page with your mouse. Scrollspy highlights "contact" and adds an "active" class to the list item (as it should). If you press "up" on your keyboard, it SHOULD go to "map", but it goes to "what we do" instead. Also, when you first press a key nothing happens. Any ideas? Live version here http://agoodman.com.au/index2.html

Comment: Addendum, this is why I liked using li.active then searching for the associated anchor tag, because it works with the scrollspy class. It seems a lot less complicated that way, can you see anything in my supplied code that would cause the double scrolling up?

Comment: I added a few limiters, such that it handles undefined and where it might exceed the list. I'd have to get scrollspy too, because I'm pretty sure it passes back the position. When you get that, you can simply append to the code above.

Comment: okay, I added a workaround, you'll have to modify the scrollspy slightly, its only one line of code. In the activate function of the prototype, it uses a variable called "this.activeTarget" which gets called each time you pass a section of your page. That value will get placed in your hidden html input. The code in the javascript will then make use of that new value.

Comment: I can see you've put a lot of effort into this, but unfortunately it's still not working - in fact, the current code makes the scrolling incredibly erratic. We're at a stage where the jquery code you've written is beyond my comprehension (I'm not well-versed in jquery) so I think it's a bit of a lost cause unfortunately.

Comment: Well that's what scrollspy does, it triggers the process function each time you scroll the page, which probably would be too much tracking for old computers or older browsers. My work around updates the hidden html input each time you pass the section, which is probably why it exhibited erratic behavior.

Comment: btw, I've tested the code I placed in my environment and it works. I have tried to fetch the variable from active function from scroll spy but apparently you can't capture that event (although it mentions on their site, they show no examples and people have had problems). However, there is another scrollspy out there that looks like they done a good job on it but its done through Mootools, not Jquery. I'd give that a go if I were you. You can create a scrollspy object and fetch the events from there much easier: http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy